# Cannot change the input background color when using jQueryUI datepicker

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add a feature that user can select a date after clicking an clock icon. I implement it by using jqueryui datepicker() component. The problem I met is that I cannot change the background color of the date input area. it is supposed  one grey color, then white, then grey etc.

[image: no changes to background image]

Here is my code:

html

```
     <ul>
            <li><span class="deltbtn"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span>set deadline<input type="text" class="datepicker"></li>
            <li><span class="deltbtn"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span>bbbbbbb<input type="text" class="datepicker"></li>
            <li><span class="deltbtn"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span>ccccccc<input type="text" class="datepicker"></li>
     </ul>
```

javascript

```
     var getinput = (function () {
    //grab text from input form
    var inputtext = $('#inputText').val();

    //empty the input form
    $('#inputText').val("");

    //create a new li and add it to the ul
    $('ul').append('<li><span class="deltbtn"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span>' + inputtext + '<input type="text" class="datepicker"></li>')

    //create deadline by using jQueryui.datepicker() component 
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: new Date() });
    });
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonImage: "deadlineicon.svg",
        buttonText: "Set Deadline"
    });
    $('ul').on('click', '.datepicker', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    })
 });
```

CSS

```
    .datepicker{
    background: #fff;
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.6rem 0.5rem;
}

.ui-datepicker-trigger { 
    position:relative;
    float: right;
    top:13px; 
    right:-170px ; 
    height:20px 
}

input:nth-of-type(2n){
    background: #f7f7f7;
}
```

any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html structure is different then you think:

Instead of

```
input:nth-of-type(2n){
    background: #f7f7f7;
}
```

try

```
li:nth-child(2n) input{
    background: red;
}
```